# What will happen to the users who installed the ProWMC package?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-media-center, windows-10-preview

I am using a windows 8.1 computer and have installed the Media Center Pack. However, Microsoft has discontinued Windows Media Center in Windows 10 and the upgrade key was changed with my license. So will I get an upgrade to Windows 10, or should I just enter my installation disk and go back to Windows 8.1 Pro?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you should not be eligible for an upgrade. Microsoft won't just leave all Media Center Pack users in the lurch like that.

Note that since it's probably too early to have any official guidance regarding this issue, there's no point jumping the gun and reverting back to 8.1 Pro right now.

Answer (score 0):

I have a test VM with 8.1 ProWMC on it. When I tried to upgrade to Win10, I was told to remove WMC first, as it was incompatible.

It looks like "leaving WMC users in the lurch" is exactly what MS is planning to do. A shame for the users, but with MS providing less and less pressure for video providers to work with WMC, the writing has really been on the wall since Win8 launch.